# Iteration n * F(n - 1)+((n - 1) * F(n - 2))

Tags: algorithm, recursion, iteration

I am stuck with this: `n * F(n - 1)+((n - 1) * F(n - 2))`, I know how to write this recursively. But no idea about the iteration.

I use this for recursion:

```
long F_r(int n)
{
    if (n <= 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (n > 2)
    {
        return n * F_r(n - 1) + ((n - 1) * F_r(n - 2));
    }
}
```

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an array for storing all intermediate values of F:

```
long F_r(int n)
{
    long[] f = new long [n + 1]; // f[0] is not used
    f[1] = 1;
    f[2] = 1;
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++)
    {
        f[i] = i * f[i - 1] + ((i - 1) * f[i - 2]); // the formula goes here
    }
    return f[n];
}
```

If you want to use only O(1) space, note that you don't need to store the whole array, only the previous two values at each point of time.
So, this can be rewritten as in [fgb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31505684/1488799).

Comment: Thank you very much! There is just a small error, you need to replace n with i :). But thanks!

Comment: @Akaike Fixed n -> i.

Answer (score 4):

To understand the iteration just simulate for `n = 3` or some other values (greater than 3 will help better). Let's start with `n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...` and see how the values of `F` gets calculated:

```
F(0) = 1;
F(1) = 1;
F(2) = 1;
F(3) = 3* F(2) + (2* F(1));
     = 3*1 + (2*1);
     = 3 + 2;
     = 5;

F(4) = 4* F(3) + (3* F(2));
     = 4*5 + (3*1);
     = 20 + 3;
     = 23;
```

And so on.

Comment: this gets a better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

To write it as an iterative algorithm, you can write something in the form of:

```
long F(int n) {
    long a = 1;
    long b = 1;
    long c = 1;
    for(int x = 3; x <= n; x++) {
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = ...
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun -- solving the recurrence relation with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%281%29%3D1%2C+f%282%29+%3D+1%2C+f%28n%29+%3D+n*f%28n-1%29+%2B+%28n-1%29*f%28n-2%29), we get:

```
F(n) = (2 * factorial(n + 2) - 5 * subfactorial(n + 2)) / (n + 1)
```

Which we can calculate as:

```
long F(int n) {
    long p = 1;
    long q = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n + 2; i++) {
        p *= i;
        q = q * i + (1 - (i % 2) * 2);
    }
    return (2 * p - 5 * q) / (n + 1);
}
```